# Einstein notation for a sum of vector elements

Tags: matrix-equations, tensor-products, tensors

Perhaps this question is misguided but I am having difficulty writing a simple matrix expression in einstein notation.

In my expression I have a vector $v$ and I wish to define the scalar value, $a$, as the sum of the components of $v$, $v^i$. I know in einstein notation you use repeated indices to represent a summation but my problem is where would the second index appear? Do I have to use a kronecker delta with one index like so perhaps:

$$a=v^i\delta_i$$

Is this the usual convention?

Comment: You shouldn't expect Einstein's notation to work nicely with this because $v\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n v^i$ does not define a tensor (as in the quantity on the right is not invariant under change of basis). Also, $\delta_i$ does not mean anything with a single index.

Comment: The expression you want is $a = u_kv^k$ where $u={\rm diag}(I)$ is the _all-ones_ vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the notion of the sum of the elements of a vector is not basis independent. So the way you would do this is to define a row-vector whose entries are all $1$s in the basis that you're working in, but note that this vector could look completely different in another basis.

I think $\delta_i$ is a logical name for this, but you might also see it called $1_i$. Then you're right, you can define the sum of the elements of $v$ as $v^i\delta_i$.

Comment: Hmm yes! That makes sense to me! I hadn't considered the possibility that my $\delta_i$ could change with the basis!

Comment: @JDoe2 One thing I've noticed is that problems involving taking the sum of elements of a vector often also involve multiplying two vectors coordinatewise. You could represent this by $u^iv^j{\delta_{ij}}^k$ where ${\delta_{ij}}^k$ has components (in a particular basis) $1$ if $i=j=k$ and $0$ otherwise. This tensor can also be used to represent a diagonal matrix; $v^j{\delta_{ij}}^k$ has the entries of $v$ as its diagonal.

Comment: Hmm yes that is actually very helpful! Thank you!